# jQuery: next() and prev() with a wrapper?

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard

I have the following html:

```
<article class="layer" id="one"> </article>
<article class="layer" id="two"> </article>
<article class="layer" id="three"> </article>

<section class="cat" id="something">    
    <article class="layer" id="four"> </article>
    <article class="layer" id="five"> </article>
</section>

<article class="layer" id="six"> </article>
…
```

I want to navigate with my keyboard through all articles. Like so …

```
var view,
        next,
        prev;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {

        view = $('.layer:in-viewport');
        next = view.next().attr('id');
        prev = view.prev().attr('id');

        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38: // Up
                if ( prev != undefined )
                    scroll($("#"+prev), true, 0);
                break;
            case 40: // Down
                if ( next != undefined )
                    scroll($("#"+next), true, 0);
                break;
        }

    });
```

This would work fine if all articles would be in the same container. However as you can see above I have a also sections that wrap those articles. I simply want to make it work as if there were no such sections and `article#three` jumps straight to `article#four`

Any idea how I could make that work?

**edit:**

The thing causing the bug in Firefox …

```
if ( top.location.hash ) {
        hash = top.location.hash.substring(3);
        catHash = hash.split('/')[1];

        if ( catHash !== undefined )
            scroll($("#"+catHash), false, 0);
        else
            scroll($("#"+hash), false, 0);

        if ( hash != "index" && !isiPhone() )
            $('#top').slideDown();  
    }
```

Where only those 4 lines cause the bug …

```
if ( catHash !== undefined )
    scroll($("#"+catHash), false, 0);
else
    scroll($("#"+hash), false, 0);
```

This few lines only check on page-load if a hash is existing in the current top.location.
So if the url is looking like this `www.something.com/#!/category/idOfElement` I want to jump to that location on the page.

Why could those 4 lines cause this bug only in firefox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to select the "real" next `<article>` elements is by using the [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) methods.

```
var allArticles = $("article.layer");
var index = allArticles.index(view);   // Zero-based indexes. Not found = -1
var prev = index <= 0 ? $() : allArticles.eq(index-1);
var next = allArticles.eq(index + 1);
```

Comment: Additionally, if you still want to select the "**real next**" `<article>` element, which is a **sibling**, use: `view.nextUntil("article.layer").andSelf().first()`. Similarly for `prev()`: `prevUntil()`.

Comment: thank you. Just perfect. Only thing I don't get is: I'm at the first article when I initially load the page. When I press my UP-key the page scrolls to the last article! This is weird and shouldn't happen. However it would be cool if it'd be the other way around so when I'm at the last article and again press the DOWN-key it scroll back to article nr1! Any idea why that happens right now?

Comment: Uhm, yes. Replace `=== -1` with `<= 0`.

Comment: Hey Rob W, I really need your help. I updated my question with my final working code. The next and prev element and the key navigation works in all Browsers except Firefox. Wether an older nor the latest version. Any idea if I'm still doing anything wrong with this. It works in all other browsers, just won't in Firefox … any ideas?

Comment: @The bug is caused by your `:in-viewport` selector. You should ask a new question about that. Also, in your `scroll` function, `selector` is already a jQuery object. So, don't rewrap it in a new jQuery object.

Comment: Ok, thank you, fixed the selector thingy in the scroll function. What am I going to ask for? Sorry for the dumb question but I have no idea what I should ask for when the bug is caused by :in-viewport. How did you find that out?

Comment: @Matt First, I looked at the `keydown` event, because the feature seemed to be implemented on a key event. Then, I checked the functions in the method. *(then I also discovered the optimization option in `scroll` function)*. At the end of the trip, I placed `console.log`, printing all local variables of the `keydown` listener, and checked the values. I noticed that the `index` was always equal to zero. So, I concluded that the `view` variable caused the error. At that point, I noticed the non-standard `:in-viewport` selector.

Comment: @Matt Regarding the question, you could post a question, referring to this question (`"Follow-up"`), with a clear description of your new problem. Title: `The ":in-viewport" selector of XXXX plugin does not work in Firefox`. Tags: At least `jQuery, <NAMEOFPLUGIN>`. In the question's body, give a clear description of the problem, plus an isolated code example, in http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: thank you very very much, I was just writing my question and while doing an example on jsbin I discovered that it does work for my example … check out http://jsbin.com/ihoqex/edit#javascript,html It's the same code as on my real example, however here it works.

Comment: @Matt Then, the title remains (for future searches). Extend the body with: `In this [isolated demo](http://jsbin.com/ihoqex/edit#javascript,html), `:in-viewport` behaves as expected. However, at [my websit](link-to-your-website), the same code seems not to work in Firefox, although it works in all other browsers.`.

Comment: Thank you again for your support. It was just a single line in css specifically for Firefox that made it buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Get a collection of all the articles, then on keypress find out which article is the current one and calculate next/prev based on their relative position(index) from the current article.  You'll need to be careful in handling the first/last article.

```
var $articles = $('.article');

$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    var view = $('.layer:in-viewport'),
        idx = $articles.index(view),
        prev = $articles.eq(Math.max(0,idx-1)),
        next = $articles.eq(Math.min(idx+1,$articles.length-1));

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38: // Up
            if ( prev != undefined )
                scroll($("#"+prev), true, 0);
            break;
        case 40: // Down
            if ( next != undefined )
                scroll($("#"+next), true, 0);
            break;
    }

});
```

You could also implement wrapping at the ends if you wanted.

Comment: The first `Math.min` should be `Math.max`. Other than that, this implementation is correct **if** the OP *always* want to select a "previous" / "next" (=self) element if there's no real "next" or "prev" element. For example, if `view` equals `"article.layer:last"`, your `next` variable will still point to the same element (`view`).