# Traverse from one UL to another UL with .next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have got myself stuck on something which seems possible, I just havent been able to figure it out for 2 days!

I have this in my .js file:

```
Mousetrap.bind('right', function() { $('li.active').next().click();  });
Mousetrap.bind('left', function() {  $('li.active').prev().click(); });
```

Above is binding the keyboard right/left to move through all LI in a UL on keypress .

I then have this in my HTML; which is two UL's.

At the moment, when I hit the last item in the first UL, it stops. I am trying to get it to jump to the next LI in the following UL.

I have tried to figure out how to use [nextAll() - Multiple list traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232082/nextall-multiple-list-traversal) but to no avail, anyone have any ideas?

```
<div class="item active">
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="trigger active" data-target="0" data-fieldclass="data1">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/sias-duplessis.jpg" alt="Sias Du Plessis"></p>
    <p>@siasduplessis</p>
    <p>#RedFury</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="1" data-fieldclass="data2">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/lance-witten.jpg" alt="Lance Witten"></p>
    <p>@LanceTheWitten</p>
    <p>#pegasus</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="2" data-fieldclass="data3">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/sasha.jpg" alt="Sasha Martinengo"></p>
    <p>@F1sasha</p>
    <p>#BallztotheWallz</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="3" data-fieldclass="data4">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/sipho.jpg" alt="Comrade Sipho"></p>
    <p>@comradesipho</p>
    <p>#badexample</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="4" data-fieldclass="data5">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/carl-wastie.jpg" alt="Carl Wastie"></p>
    <p>@carlwastie</p>
    <p>#FrickinHORSome</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="item">
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="trigger" data-target="5" data-fieldclass="data6">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/craig-stack.jpg" alt="Craig Stack"></p>
    <p>@Craig_Stack</p>
    <p>#eldiablo</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="6" data-fieldclass="data7">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/cale-pisarra.jpg" alt="Cale Pisarra"></p>
    <p>@calepissarra</p>
    <p>#thedirtyseagull</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="7" data-fieldclass="data8">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/mr-cpt.jpg" alt="Mr Cape Town"></p>
    <p>@MrCPT</p>
    <p>#goodoak</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="8" data-fieldclass="data9">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/life-is-savage.jpg" alt="Life Is Savage"></p>
    <p>@LifeisSavage</p>
    <p>#whoyourdaddy</p>
  </li>
  <li class="trigger" data-target="9" data-fieldclass="data10">
    <p class="image"><img src="images/brent-graham.jpg" alt="Brent Graham"></p>
    <p>@BrentGraham</p>
    <p>#thefalcon</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mousetrap.bind('right', function() { if($('li.active').next().hasClass("trigger"))$('li.active').next().click();
else $('li.active').closest(".item").next().find(".trigger").first().click()

});
Mousetrap.bind('left', function() { if($('li.active').prev().hasClass("trigger"))$('li.active').prev().click();
else $('li.active').closest(".item").prev().find(".trigger").last().click()

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YgfUA/5/)

You can try Chuck Norris Code too

Comment: If you go from 1->10 and then try and go again, it goes back to 6. How can I make it go back to the beginning again?

Comment: @ChrisEdington try the edited one and don't worry i will go nowhere leaving you in middle

Comment: @Ankit, this still have an issue while going back from first item of second ul. Use my answer instead of this, it doing the same, with much less code and without issues.

Comment: Thanks both of you.

@ChuckNorris when I implement your code it doesnt go past number 6?

Comment: No, it's going from 1 to 10 and backwards too.

Comment: @ChrisEdington come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32357/room-for-ankit-and-chris-horris-edington

Answer (score 5):

You can use this methods

```
function NextClick()
{
    var li = $('ul.thumbnails li.active');
    var index = $("ul.thumbnails li").index(li);

    $("ul.thumbnails li").eq(index + 1).click();
}

function PrevClick()
{
    var li = $('ul.thumbnails li.active');
    var index = $("ul.thumbnails li").index(li);

    if(index > 0)
      $("ul.thumbnails li").eq(index - 1).click();
}
```

See working example in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgfUA/1/).

Comment: To test in Jsfiddle, just click in red area, to make the answer area active. After that you can use your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Mousetrap.bind('right', function() {
    if ($('li.active').is(':last-child'))
        obj = $('li.active').parents('ul').next('ul').find('li').first();
    else obj = $('li.active').next();
    obj.click();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Chen, but it doesnt seem to be jumping to the next list? Still gets stuck on last item? REFERENCE: http://www.vadev.co.za/bts/new/parade-ring.html

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to "data-target" attribute as your reference.

you might also have a missing ending  on your markup.

```
Mousetrap.bind('right', function() {
  new_active_li = $('ul li[data-target^="' + (parseInt($('ul li.active').attr('data-target')) + 1) +'"]');
  $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  new_active_li.addClass('active');
  new_active_li.click();
});
Mousetrap.bind('left', function() {
  new_active_li = $('ul li[data-target^="' + (parseInt($('ul li.active').attr('data-target')) - 1) +'"]');
  $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  new_active_li.addClass('active');
  new_active_li.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just a simple test will do the trick like

```
var test = $("ul li.last").next().html();
if(test == 'undefined'){
    // jump to next list
    var nextList = $("li.active").parent().parent().next().find("ul");
}else{
    // the normal code
}
```